# how to add new row to such array in C#

Tags: c#

how to add new row to such array

```
 var items = new[] { 
                        new { Text = "report A", Value = "A" },                         
                        new { Text = "report E", Value = "E" }
                    };
```

Comment: Downvoting because of the clear lack of research.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are fixed size, which you need to define when instantiating the array. If you need a larger array, you need to create a new one.